# List all files in subdirectories from a given start directory

Tags: python, directory, os.path

Suppose I have a directory tree like this:

```
a/
├── b
│   ├── d.png
│   └── e
│       └── f.png
└── c.png
```

My desired output is: 
if I want to search for files in `a/b/`:
`b/d.png` & `b/e/f.png`

and in case of `a/`: `a/c.png` `a/b/d.png` `a/b/e/f.png`

I know how to list all the files in a subdirectory using os.walk and I searched a lot for similar situation like mine but I didn't find any.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
path = "a/b"
pathBase = os.path.basename(path)

for p, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(p.replace(path, pathBase),file))
```

while this works as expected with `a/b/` it doesn't work with `a/`.

Output for `a` is: `c.png` `b/d.png` `b/e/f.png` which is not as expected.

Comment: "It doesn't work." means exactly?

Comment: I edited my original post with output for `a/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be (almost) correct if you strip the trailing slash from `path`, but in any case you should use `os.path.relpath` to compute the relative file paths:

```
import os

def f(path):
    path = path.rstrip(os.sep)
    parent = os.path.dirname(path)
    for p, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            print(os.path.relpath(os.path.join(p, file), parent))
```

For what it's worth, `pathlib` makes path manipulation easier:

```
from pathlib import Path

def f(path):
    path = Path(path)
    for x in path.rglob('*'):
        if not x.is_dir():
            print(x.relative_to(path.parent))
```

Comment: The output for `path = "a/"` is still `c.png` etc, not `a/c.png` This is where I am stuck at

Comment: Aha! after your edit, this works as expected right now. But can you explain a little more why stripping the path result in the right answer?

Comment: @JonasEphrem in your original code you were replacing occurrences of `path` with `os.path.basename(path)`, which returns empty string for `path = 'a/'`. We could remove the trailing slash to make sure the name is always non-empty. OTOH for that `path` `os.path.dirname` returned `'a'`, when I expected empty string, and removing trailing slashes solves that, too. You can use [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to perform full path normalization (and not just a part of that process).